# Is there a formulaic way to reverse the order of a list in Apple Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers

For example I have a list of numbers in a column. I would like to have another column that takes whatever is in that list and reverses the order the list appears. Is there a way of doing this with a function in Apple Numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `INDIRECT` function. If you give that the string `"A1"`, it'll give you the value currently in the cell `A1`.

Let's say the list of numbers is in column `A`, and we want the reversed list in column `B`. Let's say there are 10 rows.

So: we need to make these formulae:

```
B1 = INDIRECT("A10")
B2 = INDIRECT("A9")
B3 = INDIRECT("A8")
...
B10 = INDIRECT("A1")
```

Ok. The first character of the string we are giving to `INDIRECT` here is always "A", so we can just hard code that.

Now we need the reversed row number. See the formulae above: if there are 10 rows, the reverse of row 1 is 10. The reverse of 2 is 9, and so on. So: the reverse of row *R* is *total number of rows - R + 1*.

The function `ROWS(column name)` will give us the total number of rows currently in `column name`. The function `ROW()` will give us the row number *R* (if we used `ROW()` in a formula in cell `B5`, it would return the number `5`).

So... putting the formula `INDIRECT("A" & ROWS(A) - ROW() + 1)` into each cell in column B works for me, using Numbers 3.6.1 on a Mac.

[image: Numbers screenshot, showing a list of numbers in column A, column B with the reversed list, and the INDIRECT formula discussed in the answer]